# tag is not closing in view page source even after applying the closing tag in meta sra in hbs

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, amp-ad

i was trying to use SRA tag for ad implementation

```
 <meta name="amp-ad-doubleclick-sra"/>
```

in handlebar for amp page
but when i view page source on my website, it doesn't show the closing tag it only shows `

```
<meta name="amp-ad-doubleclick-sra">
```

Answer (score 0):

That's fine, it's nothing to worry about. [`meta`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-meta-element) is a [void element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#void-elements) (it never has content). From that first link:

> [Tag omission in text/html](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#concept-element-tag-omission):
>
> No [end tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-end-tag).

In HTML, void elements have only a start tag, no end tag. The `/` just before the `>` [has no meaning](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags):

> 6. Then, if the element is one of the void elements, or if the element is a foreign element, then there may be a single U+002F SOLIDUS character (/), which on foreign elements marks the start tag as self-closing. **On void elements, it does not mark the start tag as self-closing but instead is unnecessary and has no effect of any kind.** For such void elements, it should be used only with caution — especially since, if directly preceded by an unquoted attribute value, it becomes part of the attribute value rather than being discarded by the parser.

*(my emphasis)*

The canonical HTML representation of the element doesn't have that unnecessary `/`.

The other void elements (as of this writing) are `area`, `base`, `br`, `col`, `embed`, `hr`, `img`, `input`, `link`, `source`, `track`, and `wbr`, so you'll see this with them as well.